# Listview in Cardview enable scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I m create a To Do List. Now i want to show the To Do lists in a RecylerView that contains Cards and the cards displaying a textview (title) and a Listview.

The content from Listview should be the Tasks from the TodoList.

[image]

I want to get a fix Listview without scrolling, is this possible ?

Card_Layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/abc_background_cache_hint_selector_material_light"
    android:background="@drawable/big_card"

    android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/cardList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            >

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

RecylerView.xml to show the cardview

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cardList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"


                />
```

P.s: Is this way List in List a bad solution ? Was there a better Solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

just use this call it after setting the adapter for listview like below

```
cardlist.setadapter(...);
justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(cardlist);

 public void justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {

        ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

        if (adapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        ViewGroup vg = listView;
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, vg);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams par = listView.getLayoutParams();
        par.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(par);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }
```